# iTerm in a mode I'm not familiar with. How do I get it back to normal mode

Tags: macos, iterm

When I am running on the command line using iTerm, it is in a different mode than I'm used to, shown in the images below.

[image]

[image]

When I try to type a command it shows all the previous variations of that command. When I try to run a commandit often adds other options to the command line. How do I get out of this mode?

Comment: Is this iTerm or "Terminal.app"?

Comment: iTerm.  It must have been the shell I was in because when I typed bash it changed modes.

Comment: @KevinGrabher its with iterm but not Terminal.  Any idea cause it still happens.

Comment: What is in Preferences>Profiles>>Advanced>Triggers?

Comment: @LangLangC I cannot find Triggers. When I go to Advanced I can't find keyword Triggers.

Comment: I'm wrong, i'm sorry. i found Triggers and its says "Triggers watch for text matching a regular expression to arrive in a terminal session and then perform an action in response."  But no way to turn off.

Comment: Hm. In there "edit">then delete (minus sign. lower left)?

Comment: @LangLangC When I type edit, the only line in the file is to bounce the icom until activated.

Comment: One more thing: your exact OS version and iTerm version is? And do you have 3rd party automation/productivity software installed (like Keyboard Maestro, Quicksilver, etc)?

Comment: I'm running High Sierra 10.13.6 and iterm2 version 3.2.8

Answer (score 2):

This looks like what happens when you start typing a command and then hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. The options *in* that mode are  :

> iTerm2: Highlights for New Users: [Autocomplete](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-highlights.html)
>
> Any text that exists in a tab or its scrollback buffer can be autocompleted in that tab. To use autocomplete, type the beginning of a word and then press cmd-;. An autocomplete window opens showing the top 20 choices for words beginning what you have entered. The list can be filtered by typing a subsequence. **The filter can be reset by pressing backspace. If you make a selection and press return, it will be entered for you. If you make a selection and press tab, your autocomplete will be extended with the selection.**

To just get "out of this mode" – not making a selection – hit <kbd>esc</kbd>.

This then could therefore be for this special case a setting found 'automated' in  Preferences>Profiles>Advanced>Triggers:

[image]

If that's the case, then clicking edit should open a sheet-pop-up where you see some entries, one of them providing this now unwanted feature.

[image]

In the lower left here is a plus and minus sig box. Select the unwanted trigger and delete it.

---

Alternatively, you might just create an entirely new profile (first picture with "Default" + "TUSTEP"), click the plus sign  in the lower left, and compare settings with your former "Default"-profile (in case you have some more sophisticated settings).

---

The files at

~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2

might also be worth a look.

If there are external 'input manipulators' installed (text autocompleter, scripters, listeners to events) things get more complicated…

Comment: i have added some images to my question that is rlated to your answer. i don't have a trigger to delete!  Can you check my question and look at additions i've made.

Answer (score 1):

when running iTerm click on the View menu and under that menu is an option for "Auto Command Completion". That option was selected which caused the problem mentioned in the question. When that option was deselected the iTerm windows performed as normal.